# Grails Controller Unit Testing Failure

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am experiencing this trouble: I am testing a Controller in grails (with NetBeans 6.9 and Grails 2.4.3) and while executing one of it's methods ("index") and trying to check the response url, I get a NullPointer exception as there is a custom service inside my controller which inside injected.
So I would like to know in which way I could manage that and have my service initialized correctly ?.
[image]

[image]

The sad thing comes up when I call the index method and the variable "queryService" is null. How I should test this ?

Comment: `queryService` has to be mocked inside the controller test. As this is an unit test the service class which has been injected inside the controller will not be available during test. Depending on which test framework is used (JUnit or Spock), the methodology of mocking an artifact would differ.

Comment: Thank you very much... I am in the bus stop... When I arrive home I'll check that... But meanwhile I'll google... Do you mean I should use testfor annotation for the controller and the mock annotation is for indicating which variable from my controller I would like to get instantiated ?... I'll check this... Thankx